# SlideDown form above fixed header not sliding back up

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown

I'm trying to place a slide down form above a fixed header. I can get the div to slide down but I can't get it to slide back up.

Here's my fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/w83dwwpL/

I've adapted the code in the fiddle form another which can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/darcyclarke/JNRpK/28/light/

As you can see the original fiddle did not close the div element with the same button.

The width animation in the code below isn't used.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var open = 0;
$( ".contact a" ).addClass( "open" );


    $(".contact a.close").bind("click", function(e){

        $("#contactContainer").animate({"height":"0px"}, 1000);    

        $( ".contact a" ).removeClass( "close" );
        $( ".contact a" ).addClass( "open" );

        open = 0;
    });


    $(".contact a.open").bind("click", function(e){

        $("#contactContainer").animateAuto("height", 1000); 

        $( ".contact a" ).removeClass( "open" );
        $( ".contact a" ).addClass( "close" );

        open = 1;
    });


jQuery.fn.animateAuto = function(prop, speed, callback){
var elem, height, width;
return this.each(function(i, el){
    el = jQuery(el), elem = el.clone().css({"height":"auto","width":"auto"}).appendTo("body");
    height = elem.css("height"),
    width = elem.css("width"),
    elem.remove();

    if(prop === "height")
        el.animate({"height":height}, speed, callback);
    else if(prop === "width")
        el.animate({"width":width}, speed, callback);  
    else if(prop === "both")
        el.animate({"width":width,"height":height}, speed, callback);
});  
}

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply using toggle.(You don't need to use open and close class)

Use below Code.

```
$("#contactContainer").animate({"height":"toggle"}, 1000);
```

[Check Out updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w83dwwpL/1/)